# Java - Printed 2D Array in Console is deformed

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have a very strange problem ... Today morning i printed my 2D Dungeon for testing purposes into the Eclipse - Console. It all worked fine. It kinda looked like this (only larger)

```
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

So but i had 3 versions of the 2D array, one with paths, one with unreachable rooms and the normal map. So i printed them all after another. The result is weird.

[image: Outprinted]

It seems that its completly deformed ... but i have no idea why. I just print all 3 like this :

```
    System.out.println("Dungeon begins : ");

    for(int y = 0; y < dungeon.length; y++){

        for(int x = 0 ; x < dungeon[0].length; x++){

            System.err.print(dungeon[y][x]);

        }

        System.err.println("");

    }

    System.out.println("Dungeon finished : ");
```

Normally that shouldnt happen. Also my 2D arrays, are only containing the Chars : 0,5. But the Console log shows me only 1 and 0... This only happens when i print all 3 after another. Even a pause between every print doesnt help, i tried it with Thread.Sleep();. I restarted the IDE and also my computer several times ... didnt helped.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens ? Im currently using Eclipse-Luna...

Comment: Did you print all three dungeons at the same time?

Comment: Why Python? Why C?

Comment: It is impossible to troubleshoot without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @TobiasOtto I print all those 3 dungeon right after another. So 3 times the method i posted there. So yes, "at the same time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you `System.err.print` with different threads at the same time. Please change your code so that you print to a new StringBuffer first and after that print the whole buffer at once.

```
public class Dungeon
{
    public static final String LINEBREAK = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final int[][] dungeon = new int[10][10];
        System.out.println("Dungeon begins : ");
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int y = 0; y < dungeon.length; y++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < dungeon[0].length; x++)
            {
                buffer.append(dungeon[y][x]);
            }
            buffer.append(LINEBREAK);
        }

        System.err.println(buffer.toString());
        System.out.println("Dungeon finished : ");
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work, i tried to use "buffer.append("\n");". But it gives me the same deformed output.